# In Elastic Cluster data is divided according to Index Wise not Data Wise

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a elastic cluster with 1 master node and 2 data nodes and there are 4 index in which data is divided. When My application starts it automatically creates 2 index in one data node and another 2 index in another data node and the application ingest the data in data nodes as per the indices. But when any data node failure then the data is not ingesting because 2 index are not present in another data node.

So How I distribute the data in cluster So that if any node failure then the data will ingest in available data node.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version are you using? What are the `elasticsearch.yml` of all of your nodes? How many replicas do your index have? Update your question with this information.

Comment: I am using elasticsearch-7.0.1 version and the index is showing Red if a node fails and data is not ingesting in it ,as we have another data node  : indices are looking like as  red   open index motC5ds09aRM-N_C7PLN3OkA 1 0                         
red   open index        LL29mPjkjkjjkjCfna_lJ1vKzw 1 0

Comment: Do you have any replicas for this index? If your index is red you probably do not have any replicas and the node that failed had the shards for this index. You need to provide more information, update the question with the information asked before.

Comment: Yes Previously I have only one shard thats why data is not distributing, once I have created 2 shard the data is now distributing in both data node.